# Locate for pattern in protein sequence with Biopython

Tags: python-3.x, pattern-matching, biopython

I am trying to find sequences that has a tripeptide. The tripeptide can have any other amino acids following it, except 'P'. I extracted them with the following way.

```
from Bio import SeqIO
RGD = [] 
for record in SeqIO.parse("input.fasta", "fasta"):
    rgd_count = record.seq.count('RGD')
    if rgd_count >= 1:
        RGD.append(record) 
SeqIO.write(RGD, "RGD_Proteins.fasta", "fasta")
```

How can I introduce regex in this such that, RGD(N) is fine except, RGDP ?

Thanks in advance.

AP

Comment: Does the method you use support a regex? If yes, you need something like `RGD(?!P)` (match `RGD` not followed with `P`). Perhaps, you can do it like `rgd_count = len(re.findall(r"RGD(?!P)", str(record.seq)))`. Do not forget to `import re`. Not sure you need to use `str()` though, maybe it will work with `record.seq` as a second param for `re.findall`.

Comment: I guess, it can support regex. Because, the documentation says, Bio.seq object is like string. I will try it & update ! Thanks

Comment: Please let know if it worked for you so that  I could add the answer.

Comment: I can confirm that the comment by [Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%c5%bcew) is the right solution and that [the `str()` is necessary](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/blob/master/Bio/Seq.py#L133) (otherwise you're working on a `Bio.Seq` object).

Comment: @BioGeek Sorry for bothering, I will remove the comment.

Comment: @Arun:  If it worked for you, please consider accepting the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a `re.findall` to find all non-overlapping occurrences of the regex matches in the `str(record.seq)`. Replace `record.seq.count('RGD')`

```
len(re.findall(r"RGD(?!P)", str(record.seq)))
```

Also, make sure you add `import re`.

The `RGD(?!P)` pattern matches an `RGD` substring that is not followed with `P`. The `(?!P)` is called a *negative lookahead* that fails the match if its pattern is found immediately to the right of the current location.

See [Regular-Expressions.info "Lookarounds" section](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hJo569/1).